# Custom in-buffer settings in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to define a custom in-buffer setting that I can use in my own elisp functions? For example, I want to be able to have this at the top of my script

```
#+HTML_OUTPUT_FILE: Some text
```

Then be able to get its value in my elisp code.